# celery error- worker: warm shutdown (Main Process)

Tags: python-3.x, redis, celery, python-asyncio

I am using celery for the ML model training asynchronously. If I give the task request for 2-3 times(not sure), getting the message as worker: warm shutdown(Main Process) and after that not able to send the request for a few hours. After sometimes it is automatically getting started.

My code for celery like this.

```
celery = Celery(app.name, broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')
@celery.task
```

I have tried this as well:

```
@celery.task(CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True)
```

I have tried this for setting the concurrency = 1

```
celery worker -A classify_model.celery --loglevel=info -Q random-tasks --concurrency=1
```

I am getting the error as

```
worker:warm shutdown(Main Process)
```